# Как вывести N-ый элемент из строки?

Tags: xcode, swift

У меня есть произвольная строка, в которой содержаться буквы и цифры. Допустим мне нужно вывести из нее 5-ый и 7-ой символ и если эти символы - цифры, то привести их к типу `Int`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Работа со строками расписана в любом учебнике по swift очень подробно. С символами - тоже. Что конкретно вам непонятно?

Comment: кому то серьезно "непонятна суть вопроса"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну типа такого

```
let str = "ABCDEF6"

let seventhSymbol = str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)]
print("седьмой символ: \(seventhSymbol)")
if let test:Int = Int(String(seventhSymbol)) {
    print("это цифра \(test)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Синтаксис нужного вам языка не знаю, но на общем примере:
В цикле сделать условие (Если такой-то номер элемента равен n, то взять переменную типа `int` и присвоить ей значение как-то функцией перевести из `char` в `int`). Ах да, в условии можно поставить проверку на то есть ли это цифры по ASCII таблице.